# "~>plasma_desktop" errors in linux mint 17.3, kde4. Unable to figure out where to start to address instabilities

Tags: linux-mint, kde, plasma, kde4

Upon restart of plasma-desktop I encountered the following output:

https://pastebin.com/nSgv9WyG

It points towards some serious instabilities. I have been searching for 
an idea of what to try to begin addressing the problem, but have hit a 
bit of a wall.

One suggestion was to remove and re-install `akanodi`, but this proved unwise as it threatens to break many other current running 
packages. Not really sure what more to try.

It all started with me trying to address the fact that my folder view widgets always move into a stack at the bottom right corner of my desktop upon reboot, so I thought maybe if i force a restart of the plasma-desktop service, it may save the locations properly into the config file, and encountered the fore-mentioned errors posted in the pastebin link above.

Comment: this almost certainly has nothing to do with akonadi.  try this to restart the plasma desktop: `kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart plasmashell`

Comment: > kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart plasmashell
No command 'kquitapp5' found, did you mean:
 Command 'kquitapp' from package 'kde-runtime' (universe)
kquitapp5: command not found

Comment: dropping the '5' from 'kquitapp5' yielded: ~> kquitapp plasmashell && kstart plasmashell
kquitapp(29943): "Application plasmashell could not be found using service org.kde.plasmashell and path /MainApplication."

Comment: no idea, i don't use kde.  that's what i found when i googled 'restart plasma desktop'.  it seems that the page i found is obsolete now - the significant point seems to be using `kstart` to restart the plasma shell, whatever it's current name is.

Comment: using kstart gave the same output, I started with akanodi as a possible cause of problems due to the last 4 lines of output:               ProcessControl: Application 'akonadiserver' returned with exit code 255 (Unknown error)
"akonadiserver" crashed too often and will not be restarted! 
plasma-desktop(2217)/libakonadi Akonadi::EntityTreeModelPrivate::finalCollectionFetchJobDone: "Unknown error." 
plasma-desktop(2217)/libakonadi Akonadi::EntityTreeModelPrivate::collectionFetchJobDone: Job error:  "Unknown error." for collection: ()

Comment: You can't start plasma-desktop like this because you must already have KCM (configuration) setup, X session, environment (including fonts, themes, etc for X/qt), environment for XDG setup, then dbus connection and then KSM (the desktop session) ALL before you'd start plasa-desktop.

Comment: kcm not installed. I have a good setup, just some widgets that move on their own, but my primary concern is just the long list of errors that reveal the instabilities.

Answer (score 0):

On most distributions your login manager sets up your session. Simply killing plasma and restarting it isn't sufficient as this leaves your session (called ksm) in an already configured state. While what you probably should do is restart your session if you want to restart plasma you need to at least restart the shell.

kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell

Note that this will not be started by the session manager when you do this. Which leaves ksm in a weird state. You will have to stop plasmashell yourself before you end of your session.

Comment: kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart plasmashell No command 'kquitapp5' found, did you mean: Command 'kquitapp' from package 'kde-runtime' (universe) kquitapp5: command not found

Comment: also, more interested in tracking down the source of the errors, getting QBusErrors, akanodi errors, qt errors, missing paths, restarting plasma-desktop is just the action that revealed the underlying issues. see output @ https://pastebin.com/nSgv9WyG